# Incrementing in a list efficiently

Tags: arrays, performance, increment

I have a list:

```
foo = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Currently, I increment a known number of consecutive indices by a given value:

```
def increment(index, length, some_value, a_list):
    for i in range(index, index+length):
        a_list[i] += some_value
    return a_list
foo = increment(2,3,4,foo) 
# [0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

However, the problem is that I would be doing this over a range of 50-100 "length" and would be doing this millions of times. So, my looping would pose a considerable problem to computational time (I believe). Is there a way to add a given value to all indices within a given range without having to loop through the given indices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simon Tatham wrote something about "Cumulative Frequency Tables": http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/algorithms/cumulative.html
This would apparently get you log times:

```
def increment(index, length, some_value, a_frequency_table):
    // increment "frequency" of (index) by some_value
    // decrement "frequency" of (index+length-1) by some_value
```

He also links C-code on the bottom of the page. If I understood your question right, it should be possible to adopt.

Comment: But it might require changes to other code using this array. If this is a project with lots of code and/or people it might be not worth it.

Comment: This algorithm would work. It does require quite a bit of re-coding, but fortunately it is a single man project. The big hang up is that I'm working with a huge dataset. Million indices and millions of increments, each increment covering 50-100 indices. To cover the remedy the memory needs of all the indices, I have a sub-index tiling over the the theoretical total (outputting to file the past), as my increments are sorted by starting index. This will further tweaking of the provided algorithm to account for window shifts.

Answer (score 0):

Given your requirements, it looks to me as though you doing this correctly in regards to performance. The only thing I can see to improve performance is very miniscule... I wouldn't bother returning the array, as it is unnecessary.  Beyond that, everything looks sound.

```
def increment(index, length, some_value, a_list):
for i in range(index, index+length):
    a_list[i] += some_value

increment(2,3,4,foo) 
# [0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: The return was unnecessary. Just to make clear the point in the code. It's actually an object with a mutable array.